# Alternatives to eval in bash

Tags: bash

In Bash scripting, the eval command is often used to execute dynamically generated code. However, I have read that eval can be risky as it can lead to security vulnerabilities and make the code harder to maintain. Therefore, it's generally recommended to avoid using eval whenever possible.

Are there other alternative approaches I can use in bash scripting ?

This is what I am currently using

```
## start of file
shstate=$(shopt -p extglob)
shopt -s extglob

## sourcing a library here

eval "$shstate"
## end of file
```

Comment: `shopt -q extglob && shstate=s || shstate=u` before and `shopt -$shstate extglob` after?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Comment: If you script is being *executed* (not sourced), there's no reason to restore the setting of `extglob` in the first place, because the shell with that setting exits immediately after you restore the original value.

Comment: It is being sourced as part of a library utility for interactive use.

Comment: There's essentially no danger in leaving `extglob` turned on permanently.  It's turned on by default in some Bash installations anyway.  See [Is it dangerous to always have extglob on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276911/264812).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could read the `shopt -p` output into an array, and then execute the array as a command:

```
read -ra current_setting < <(shopt -p extglob)
shopt -s extglob

# do stuff

"${current_setting[@]}"   # restore previous setting
```

Comment: This is `eval` under disguise and exposes the same vulnerability as the original solution. Just check what happens if the "stuff" is `current_setting=(ls -l)`.

Comment: In what bash version will `shopt -p extglob`  output `ls -l`?

Comment: Where your answer says _"# do stuff"_, the question reads _"## sourcing a library here"_. If that library incidentally uses a variable named `current_setting` and stores in it an array like `(rm -rf)`, go figure what `"${current_setting[@]}"` does.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative :

```
shopt -q extglob || { shopt -s extglob; unset_extglob=1; }

## sourcing a library here

test -v unset_extglob && shopt -u extglob
```

Comment: Right.  In this one I do not need to have commands in a variable.

Comment: And you only do `shopt -s extglob` when it's not defined.

Answer (score 0):

`shopt -q extglob` does not print anything (because of `-q`) and its exit status tells if the option is enabled (on success) or disabled (on failure).

You can use this to save the state and restore it later without using `eval`:

```bash
# Save the status of `shopt`
shopt -q extglob
shstate=$?

shopt -s extglob


# Run some code
# ...


# Restore the status of `shopt`
if [ "$shstate" -eq 0 ]; then
  shopt -s extglob
else
  shopt -u extglob
fi
```

Comment: It does actually give `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: Please define "it".

Comment: A reference to the command `shopt -q extglob`

Comment: In this answer I suggest to use `-q` which means "quiet", not `-p` (which means "print"). Check the [documentation of `shopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) in the Bash manual.

Comment: What is the rational behind your approach (-q versus -p) ?  Perhaps one can have the option to decide between the two.

Comment: Between which two? You asked how to restore the state of `extglob` without running `eval` because the script sources another script, the included script can overwrite the variable where the command to restore the state of `extglob` has been saved. My answer does not use `eval`. It queries the state of `extglob` and stores the value in a variable. Then it checks the value of the variable and restores the state of `extglob`. If the variable is overwritten the state of `extglob` might be reset incorrectly but there is no risk of injection (because there is no `eval`).

Comment: If you do not source another file then there is nothing wrong with your solution using `eval`.

Comment: Selection of whether to use `shopt -q extglob` or  `shopt -p extglob`.  The command `shopt -q extglob` seems more specific because in inquires directly about whether `extglob` is enabled or not.  But then `shopt -p extglob` tells you exactly the command to revert.  Whereas with `shopt -q extglob` I would have to reconstruct the command myself.

Comment: You want to run a command but you don't want to use `eval`. Here the problem is not `eval`, the problem is that the value of `$shstate` can be replaced by the library sourced before it is `eval`-ed. As long as there is chance to be overwritten, no matter how you execute it, with or without using `eval`, the result is the same: it is a security vulnerability.